# Download filename contain "~" character turn to "-" in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, httpresponse

When download filename contain "~" character, google chrome auto change "~" to "-" but this doesn't happen in IE, edge, firefox.
I already check in response header: content-disposition: attachment; filename="sample~.xlsx"

Any explain for this different.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are correct, i have checked and here even '-' symbol is also removed from the filename ! may be to add more security they implemented this purposely. Can you please specify the purpose ? do you need this symbol to be in the downloaded file !?

Comment: this is request from my client, any file was download from server must be have same name, even that file contain special character. but I can't find out why chrome change '~' to '-'.